# Vim minibufexplorer to show only buffers from current vim tab

Tags: vim, tabs, minibufexplorer

I really like minibufexplorer so I always have an eye on which buffers I opened. Recently, I discovered vim tabs. I think the combination of both could be very powerful for my workflow.

Unfortunately, when I open two vim tabs with multiple buffers in each, minibufexplorer shows me *all* the buffers in each. Example: I open the buffers A, B, C in tab 1 and the buffers C, D, E in tab 2. Now, I'd like minibufexplorer in tab 1 to show me only A, B, and C and in tab 2 to show C, D, and E. What it currently does is to show A, B, C, D, E in both tabs.

Is that inherent in how tabs and minibufexplorer works, or is there something I can do?

Comment: personally, I feel confused instead of "powerful" if I use both tabs and buffers.. :) Good luck..

Comment: Just as an update, I am now happily using the [CtrlP](https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim.git) plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buffers are not specific to one tab: buffer A may be displayed in windows 3 and 4 of tab 1 and in window 1 of tab 2 or… nowhere. You'll probably need to hack MBE a little to narrow down the list to the buffers currently visible in the current tab.

But what would be the point?

If you have buffers A and B already displayed in windows 1 and 2 of the current tab, displaying a list of those two buffers sounds beyond useless to me.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I feared :/ I usually have more buffers open than I have windows, that way I can switch between files I am currently working on by simple `:b1` instead of `:e path/to/file`.

Comment: Try `:bn` and `:bp` as well as `:b <Tab>`.